# log4net: Configure to ignore messages from a specific class

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

Is there a way to have the log4net configuration ignore a specific class? For example, we generally create a log in every class. Similar to this:

```
private static readonly ILog Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("MyClass");
```

The problem is `MyClass` logs an extreme amount of data and it gets hard to find information about other classes. Its another dev that uses `MyClass` so I cannot just go in and change around the log files, but in my environment I would like to ignore these.

Can I set my `configuration` file to ignore the messages from a specific class?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Sure, use a [filter.](http://www.claassen.net/geek/blog/2009/06/log4net-filtering-by-logger.html)

Here's the snippet posted on the blog, for future reference - all credit to the author of that blog post:

```
<filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
  <!-- allows this sub-namespace to be logged... -->
  <loggerToMatch value="Noisy.Namespace.But.Important" />
</filter>
<filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
  <!-- ...but not the rest of it -->
  <loggerToMatch value="Noisy.Namespace" />
  <acceptOnMatch value="false" />
</filter>
```

Answer (score 60):

A filter certainly works but I would prefer to turn off the logger (or logger hierarchy) directly like this:

```
<logger name="YourNameSpace.WithNoLogging" additivity="false">
    <level value="OFF" />        
</logger>
<logger name="MyClass" additivity="false">
    <level value="OFF" />        
</logger>
<root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="YourAppender" />
</root>
```

Assuming that `YourNameSpace.WithNoLogging` is a namespace then the shown configuration would disable logging on the entire name space. The second "example" turns off logging for your class (according to your question).

Comment: does it work with 3rd party assemblies? I'm trying to ignore RavenDb messages, no luck so far

Comment: I actually managed to do it - by specifying full name of the class that was logging, somehow namespace with an asterisk didn't do it

Comment: Stefan, yep, that's on the server side

Comment: Wildcards do not work, but you can specify a namespace instead of a class: then all classes in this namespace (and in child namespaces) will be affected

Comment: Hi, i think this only works if you use getLogger(myclass) for each Class. If you generate a named logger on applicationstart and use this by reference in your complete application, it will not work. Or am I incorrect in that point?

Comment: @swe: you are correct. I prefer to use different loggers per class since it offers a lot more flexibility.

Comment: I like the idea, but I'll go for filters as I don't want the _censorship_ to happen for all appenders, only for the DB one.

Comment: Based on [documentaion](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html#loggers), the `aditivity` attribute must be `true` (default value) for logger to inherit appenders from parent logger. If you specify it as `false` then you need to specify also the appender. Your code might seem to work as you specify level `OFF` but if you used e.g. `WARNING` to only reduce the logging, there will be still no entries in the log for `YourNameSpace.WithNoLogging` and `MyClass` loggers unless you remove the `aditivity` attribute.

Answer (score 16):

I would suggest using [Filters](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/introduction.html) as well. However, since I struggled finding the whole picture when I was trying to implement the filter I am posting a sample snippet of the `Configutation file` I created which points out where filters go.

The filter you are going for in this case would be

> log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter ----(Matches against a the start of the
>   logger name.)

**Hint:** In the `config` file for **Log4Net** it is important where you put your tags and the priority of them actually matters. So in this case `<filter>` tag comes after the `<appender>`opening tag and before it's `<file value = ... />` tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
    </configSections>
    <log4net>
        <appender name="RollingFile.PassedDevices" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
            <filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
                <loggerToMatch value="Foo.namespace.bar.mySubclass" />
                <acceptOnMatch value="false" />
            </filter>
            <file value="myPassedDevices.log" />
            <appendToFile value="true" />
            <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
            <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%timestamp    %level  - %message  [%thread]       %logger%newline" />
            </layout>
        </appender>
        <root>
            <level value="DEBUG" />
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" /> <!-- My other appender which logs all and I cut it out in this snippet. Remember that you should reference all your appenders in this tag to make them work.-->
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFile.PassedDevices" />
        </root>
    </log4net>
</configuration>
```

In this technique you can have multiple `appenders` which you can redirect the logging results of a specific logger to a separate `appender` instead of ignoring them. Such as one `appender` for all logs and one for the filtered out logs for a specific `class`.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try to apply a category to your own messages
Try this thread: 
[How to add category prefix to log4net message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4454755/how-to-add-category-prefix-to-log4net-message)

Comment: I appreciate your hint. My filter was not working until I moved it before the 'file value =...'

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to post the common exclusions if you are using NHibernate and log4net.  Note that each filter needs its own element.

```
<filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
    <loggerToMatch value="NHibernate.Engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.ProxyWarnLog" />
    <acceptOnMatch value="false" />
  </filter>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
    <loggerToMatch value="NHibernate.LazyInitializationException" />
    <acceptOnMatch value="false" />
  </filter>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
    <loggerToMatch value="NHibernate.Cache.NoCacheProvider" />
    <acceptOnMatch value="false" />
  </filter>
```