# log4net: How to turn off logging of an assembly reference?

Tags: c#, log4net

In my project I use log4net for logging. My project has a reference to a DLL, which also uses log4net for logging. Now I am facing the problem, that my logfile has both outputs: The messages from my own code and also the messages from the reference.

How can I turn off logging for the referenced DLL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alternatively to Ash Burlaczenko's answer, you could also filter those messages from the foreign namespace, like so:

```
<filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
  <!-- allows this sub-namespace to be logged... -->
  <loggerToMatch value="Noisy.Namespace.But.Important" />
</filter>
<filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
  <!-- ...but not the rest of it -->
  <loggerToMatch value="Noisy.Namespace" />
  <acceptOnMatch value="false" />
</filter>
```

(Copied XML from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504148/log4net-configure-to-ignore-messages-from-a-specific-class))

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a logger just for your namespace

```
<logger name="YourNamespace.SubNamespace">
    <appender-ref ref="YourAppender" />
</logger>
```

Then only logging in that namespace will be sent to YourAppender.