# EPiServer routing issues

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing, episerver-7

I've implemented a few css files in an EPiServer 7 MVC application.

```
<link href="/Static/Web/CSS/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Static/Web/CSS/print.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

The routing may be a bit trigger happy since when I look at the logs this shows up in the log after every page load.

```
DEBUG EPiServer.Shell.Web.Routing.ModuleRouteCollection: Not routing '~/Static/CSS/print.css' since it doesn't start with '~/EPiServer/Shell/2.0.86'
DEBUG EPiServer.Shell.Web.Routing.ModuleRouteCollection: Not routing '~/Static/CSS/print.css' since it doesn't start with '~/EPiServer/EPiServer.Packaging.UI/2.0.86'
DEBUG EPiServer.Shell.Web.Routing.ModuleRouteCollection: Not routing '~/Static/CSS/print.css' since it doesn't start with '~/EPiServer/CMS/2.0.79'
DEBUG EPiServer.Shell.Web.Routing.ModuleRouteCollection: Not routing '~/Static/CSS/print.css' since it doesn't start with '~/episerver'
DEBUG EPiServer.Shell.Web.Routing.ModuleRouteCollection: Not routing '~/Static/CSS/print.css' since it doesn't start with '~/modules'
DEBUG EPiServer.Shell.Web.Routing.ModuleRouteCollection: Not routing '~/Static/CSS/main.css' since it doesn't start with '~/EPiServer/Shell/2.0.86'
DEBUG EPiServer.Shell.Web.Routing.ModuleRouteCollection: Not routing '~/Static/CSS/main.css' since it doesn't start with '~/EPiServer/EPiServer.Packaging.UI/2.0.86'
DEBUG EPiServer.Shell.Web.Routing.ModuleRouteCollection: Not routing '~/Static/CSS/main.css' since it doesn't start with '~/EPiServer/CMS/2.0.79'
DEBUG EPiServer.Shell.Web.Routing.ModuleRouteCollection: Not routing '~/Static/CSS/main.css' since it doesn't start with '~/episerver'
DEBUG EPiServer.Shell.Web.Routing.ModuleRouteCollection: Not routing '~/Static/CSS/main.css' since it doesn't start with '~/modules'
```

Why does it try to route the included files and how do I disable it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EPiServer adds a few routes to the `RouteTable` that are used for CMS/Admin/Modules etc.

When you request /Static/Web/CSS/main.css the routing will go through the route table in order and try to find the first route that matches. The `ModuleRouteCollection` route will only match if the URL starts with ~/episerver or ~/modules etc. If it doesn't it will log a debug-message, but only if you have configured log4net to log debug messages.

If you want to avoid these messages you could have a look at this StackOverflow post "[log4net: Configure to ignore messages from a specific class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504148/log4net-configure-to-ignore-messages-from-a-specific-class)" and ignore the "EPiServer.Shell.Web.Routing.ModuleRouteCollection" namespace.

Typical route table for an EPiServer 7 site:

```
[0]: {[ModuleRouteCollection RoutePath="~/episerver/Shell/2.1.90", Routes=[Shellepi,Shelldgrid,Shellput-selector,Shellxstyle]]}
[1]: {[ModuleRouteCollection RoutePath="~/episerver/EPiServer.Packaging.UI/2.1.90", Routes=[EPiServer.Packaging.UIepi-packaging]]}
[2]: {[ModuleRouteCollection RoutePath="~/episerver/CMS/2.1.82", Routes=[CMSepi-cms,CMStinymce,CMSepi/cms]]}
[3]: {[ModuleRouteCollection RoutePath="~/modules", Routes=[App]]}
[4]: {[ModuleRouteCollection RoutePath="~/episerver", Routes=[CMS,EPiServer.Packaging,EPiServer.Packaging.UI,Shell,Find]]}
[5]: {EPiServer.Web.Routing.StaticFileRemapRoute}
[6]: {EPiServer.Web.Routing.StopRoutingForExistingFileRoute}
[7]: {System.Web.Mvc.RouteCollectionExtensions.IgnoreRouteInternal}
[8]: {EPiServer.Web.Routing.ContentRoute}
[...]
```