# Trace Listeners - How to Suppress log messages from given Namespace?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, log4net, trace

I'm working on a project that is using a custom trace listener:

```
<system.diagnostics>
<trace>
  <listeners>
    <add name="CustomTraceListener" type="CustomTraceListener, CustomTraceListener" />
  </listeners>
</trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

And I have a class that logs way too much:

```
namespace MyApp.SuperChatty{
   //I log too much
   public class HeavyLogger{
   }
}
```

**How can I suppress `Verbose` messages from `MyApp.SuperChatty.HeavyLogger`?**

When I used log4net, I could create a specific logger for a given class or namespace ([log4net: Configure to ignore messages from a specific class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504148/log4net-configure-to-ignore-messages-from-a-specific-class)), so how can I do this with Tracing?

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I can think of is to create a custom `TraceFilter` ([TraceFilter at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracefilter.aspx)). I've never done this myself, but I would expect that you could then provide a namespace/partial namespace to `InitializeData` and then determine whether or not to trace from a source in the `ShouldTrace` method.

Comment: So it's not possible through config only?

Comment: Well, you'd implement the class and then configure it in the config. (But like I said, I haven't actually done this myself, so my response is only theoretical.)