# Log4Net multiple configurations in single config file

Tags: c#, log4net

Is there any possibility to create single *log4net.config* file **containing multiple configurations**. I would like to create different logs depending on some kind of parameter that will choose proper configuration with appenders from logger config file.

e.g. I have two different projects, in each of them I need to create different logs. By reading the same for both projects config file in *assembly.info* and giving some kind of parameter i could choose different logger configurations to be used in projects.

I would be grateful for any help with it.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to accomplish - you can define as many appenders and loggers as you wish to in the configuration and swap them around at runtime with code, is that what you're after?

Comment: you can have only 1 config but different filters to deal with different cases

Comment: @stuartd what ' trying to acomplish is to have one log4net.config file in solution which will be added (Add existing) to each project. This file should contain each project logger configuration and project should choose the one that is assigned to it (other loggers should be ignored).

Comment: It sounds like you can do that, as you can define loggers per namespace, which means they will operate on a per-project basis - so loggers are called Company.Namespace.Project1, Company.Namespace.Project2 etc (the logger names are inherited so apply to the whole project)

Comment: @stuartd it works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Basically everything you can do is mentioned here:
https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html

and examples are here:

https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html

Now, initializing your Logger you can choose the config file to be used. If you want it to be all in the app config file, then you simply provide ONE configuration.
However, if you need to have different behavior for different cases (projects/classes), just specify filters that will decide which appender should be used in a moment.

Filter can base on the class name, ex. check here as it was already discussed:
[log4net: Configure to ignore messages from a specific class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5504148/log4net-configure-to-ignore-messages-from-a-specific-class)