# Use of log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator in AssmblyInfo.cs file

Tags: c#, configuration, log4net

I have seen the following way to include an external log4net config file or app.config in an ASP.NET :

`[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]`

My question is : Is this line of code is responsible for triggering of creation of  all referenced Appenders files? Is there any other way to refer app.config while using log4net for creating logs ?

Problem : 
There are two appenders to be used in two different files respectively but when any one file is getting called, two log files are getting generated for both appenders which is not required. One file call should generate one log file based on appender name object.

Reference question :
[How to create different log files for different classes in one application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42806626/how-to-create-different-log-files-for-different-classes-in-one-application?noredirect=1#comment72728326_42806626)

Comment: Yes, and you can also use `XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch();` but that won't solve your problem.

Comment: @stuartd, what can be done ?

Comment: If the file really bothers you that much, you can write code to delete it in your app after the configuration has beel loaded. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343749/get-log4net-log-file-in-c-sharp) for how to get the path.