# context scope at logger level

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

Is there a way to set a context property value in log4net at logger level? We have scopes at thread context and global context and so on. I was wondering if there is a way to set a context variable at the logger instance level?

I know such thing does not exist but to make my point, it would be like

```
 private static ILog _Log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

_Log.LoggerContext.Properties["myVar"] = "someValue";
//now every log with this logger will use somevalue for the myVar property.
```

Is there a way to do such thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, that capability does not exist in log4net (or NLog for that matter).  I do have an idea that should work.  I don't know if it is a "good" idea or not, I will leave that for you to decide...

Briefly, you could write a custom PatternLayoutConverter ([see this post for one example of how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961815/custom-log4net-property-patternlayoutconverter-with-index)).  This converter will look for a "context" in your own static dictionary (similar to the static dictionary contexts that log4net already has).  The "context" will be stored by logger name.  The value in the dictionary will be *another* dictionary that will hold your variables.

This a little bit more involved than I am prepared to get into right now, but I will try to give some good pseudocode to show how it might work...

UPDATE:

I have added an implementation that works (at least in the minimal testing that I have done).  I have defined a "context" to hold a property bag for each logger.  I have also implemented a PatternLayoutConverter to retrieve the properties for a given logger.

(The code formatting does not seem to be honoring indentation).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using log4net;
using log4net.Util;
using log4net.Layout.Pattern;

using log4net.Core;

namespace Log4NetTest
{
  //
  // Context container for loggers.
  // Indexable by logger or logger name.
  //
  public interface IContext
  {
    IContextProperties this [ILog logger] { get; }
    IContextProperties this [string name] { get; }
  }

  //
  // Context properties for a specific logger.
  //
  public interface IContextProperties
  {
    object this [string key] { get; set; }
    void Remove( string key );
    void Clear( );
  }

  //
  // Static class exposing the logger context container.
  //
  public static class LoggerProperties
  {
    private static readonly IContext context = new LoggerContext();

    public static IContext Properties { get { return context; } }
  }

  internal class LoggerContext : IContext
  {
    private readonly IDictionary<string, IContextProperties> dict = new Dictionary<string, IContextProperties>();

    #region IContext Members

    //
    // Get the properties asociated with this logger instance.
    //
    public IContextProperties this [ILog logger]
    {
      get
      {
        ILoggerWrapper w = logger as ILoggerWrapper;
        ILogger i = w.Logger;

        return this[i.Name];
      }
    }

    //
    // Get the properties associated with this logger name.
    //
    public IContextProperties this [string name]
    {
      get 
      {
        lock (dict)
        {
          IContextProperties props;
          if ( dict.TryGetValue( name, out props ) ) return props;
          props = new LoggerContextProperties();
          dict [name] = props;
          return props;
        }
      }
    }

    #endregion
  }

  //
  // Implementation of the logger instance properties.
  //
  internal class LoggerContextProperties : IContextProperties
  {
    private readonly IDictionary<string, object> loggerProperties = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    #region IContextProperties Members

    public object this [string key]
    {
      get
      {
        lock ( loggerProperties )
        {
          object value;
          if ( loggerProperties.TryGetValue( key, out value ) ) return value;
          return null;
        }
      }
      set
      {
        lock ( loggerProperties )
        {
          loggerProperties [key] = value;
        }
      }
    }

    public void Remove( string key )
    {
      lock ( loggerProperties )
      {
        loggerProperties.Remove( key );
      }
    }

    public void Clear( )
    {
      lock ( loggerProperties )
      {
        loggerProperties.Clear();
      }
    }

    #endregion
  }

  public class LoggerContextPropertiesPatternConverter : PatternLayoutConverter
  {
    protected override void Convert( System.IO.TextWriter writer, LoggingEvent loggingEvent )
    {
      IContextProperties props = LoggerProperties.Properties[loggingEvent.LoggerName];
      object value = props[Option];
      if (value != null)
      {
        writer.Write(value);
      }
      else
      {
        writer.Write("{0}.{1} has no value", loggingEvent.LoggerName, Option);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Configure the appender to use the PatternLayoutConverter:

```
<appender name="debug" type="log4net.Appender.DebugAppender">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %logger %-5p [LOGPROP = %LOGPROP{test}] %m%n"/>
    <converter>
      <name value="LOGPROP" />
      <type value="Log4NetTest.LoggerContextPropertiesPatternConverter" />
    </converter>
  </layout>
</appender>
```

How to set the properties for a logger:

```
  ILog loga = LogManager.GetLogger("A");
  ILog logb = LogManager.GetLogger("B");
  ILog logc = LogManager.GetLogger("C");

  LoggerProperties.Properties[loga]["test"] = "abc";
  LoggerProperties.Properties[logb]["test"] = "def";
  LoggerProperties.Properties[logc]["test"] = "ghi";

  loga.Debug("Hello from A");
  logb.Debug("Hello from B");
  logc.Debug("Hello from C");
```

The output:

```
A: 2011-07-19 10:17:07,932 [1] A DEBUG [LOGPROP = abc] Hello from A
B: 2011-07-19 10:17:07,963 [1] B DEBUG [LOGPROP = def] Hello from B
C: 2011-07-19 10:17:07,963 [1] C DEBUG [LOGPROP = ghi] Hello from C
```

Good luck!