# app.config read value of key connection string from other node

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, app-config

On stackoverflow are a couple of questions regarding how the [get app.config values from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10766654/appsettings-get-value-from-config-file) or [using windows path variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642570/accessing-appsettings-config-values-from-log4net-config-section).

- But I would like to know if i can use an already defined key inside the app.config xml file?
- The purpose is to avoid entereing the connection string many times.

Below you can see my connection string 'con_str':

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="con_str" value="myDatabaseConnectionString"/>
</appSettings>
....
<log4net>
    <appender name="AdoNetExceptionAppender" 
         type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
      <bufferSize value="1" />
      <threshold value="FATAL"/>
      <connectionType ... />
      <connectionString 
                 value= .... <--- How to use value from 'con_str' above?
       />
      <commandText ... />
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_date" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
      </parameter>
    </appender>
</log4net>
```

Is there a way to read the value of the key `con_str` from the `appSettings`node within app.config?

#### Update 1 after comment from user chadiusvt

I changed my app.config like this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="con_strOrig" value="foo" />   
</appSettings>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="connStr" connectionString="foo" />   
</connectionStrings>
    ...
<log4net>
  <appender name="AdoNetExceptionAppender" 
            type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="1" />
  <threshold value="FATAL"/>
  <connectionType ... />
  <connectionString value="connStr"  />
  ...
```

As you can see with the last update it is possible to reference the `connectionStrings`. But since in my code i always use appSettings i would have to change my code in many places. 
Is there a way to let the `<appSettings>` point to the `connStr` key from the node  `<connectionsStrings>`?

#### Update 2 to adress the answer

I believe you misunderstood. I am looking for a way to reference another var inside the xml-file.

Comment: Maybe [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441359/can-you-pull-the-connectionstring-for-a-log4net-adonetappender-from-elsewhere-in) would be of help?  It doesn't specify the connectionstring by name, but if you only have one, this might be sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use this line :

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["con_str"]
```

Comment: I believe you misunderstood. I would like to reference the value from the connectionstring from inside the app.config xml-file. The following did not work: `<connectionString value=System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["con_str"]  />`

Comment: you can use the line above to READ the settings then by code set the log 4 net equals to that one. so you only have 1 to manage.

Comment: yes like in program.cs when you start the application you can override these settings. just read the "con_str" and set the log4net one.

Answer (score 1):

As of my knowledge it's not possible to assign the  section name with  values.

I've some alternative solution to accomplish your task.

Assign   name in to  value dynamically in Program.CS

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager
  .ConnectionStrings["connStr"].ConnectionString;
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings
  .Set("con_strOrig", connectionString);
```