# Log4net error - patternstring not working

Tags: c#, log4net

I am creating a logging component using `log4net` in my project. I've created an xml file to configure the `log4net` settings including an append-er and logger definition. I'm using `PatternString` to pick up properties' value from the `appsetting.config` file. However when I build and run the project, it throws the following error:

`log4net:ERROR Undefined level [%property{Level}] on Logger [Test].`

Does anyone know what might be causing it?

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<log4net>
  <logger name="Test">
    <level type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{Level}" />
    <appender-ref ref="JsonFileAppender" />
  </logger>
</log4net>
```

**appsetting.config**:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="Level" value="ALL"/>
</appSettings>
```

In case it's useful the `log4net` version is: **version:2.0.8**

Answer (score 1):

Good question!

I learnt from this, a lot.

Please don't forget to call this method before start logging.

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

app.config is.

1. if you need apply pattern, use `<layout>` element.
2. and if you want to use some value from "appSettings", 
   use like this,  `%appSetting{Environment}`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>

      <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
      </configSections>

      <log4net>
          <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender" >
              <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                  <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%ndc] - %message%newline" />
              </layout>
          </appender>
          <root>
              <level value="%appSetting{Environment}" />
              <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
          </root>
      </log4net>     

      <appSettings>
        <add key="Environment" value="INFO" />
        <!-- this is optional flag.-->
        <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="True" />    
      </appSettings>  
    </configuration>
```

Here is where I learned

- [Accessing appSettings config values from log4net config section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642570/accessing-appsettings-config-values-from-log4net-config-section)
- https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html
- https://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2010/11/12/log4net-appsettings-keys.aspx/

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is because the level of a logger can't be configured via a `PatternString`.
The `<level>` elements expects a wellknown value, like eg. `ALL`, `DEBUG`, `INFO`, `WARN`, `ERROR`,
eg.:

```
<logger name="Test">
    <level value="All" />
</logger>
```

---

From your setup I read that you are trying to apply a setting from `AppSettings.config` upon the log level of a logger in your `Log4net` configuration.
As explained above, this can't be done.

Either keep all `Log4net` related settings within its own `xml` - in the end it is also configuration.

Or set the level programmatically;
you will have to translate the `string` value in `appsettings.config` to a `Level` yourself.

```
logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Test");
Level level = // Parse from ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Level"]
((Logger)logger.Logger).Level = level;
```